# How to access item bucket search filters from within Experience Editor

Tags: experience-editor, buckets

I'm using an item bucket for an article content type.  For this project, we're trying to empower the author to do as much work as possible within the Experience Editor, and hopefully stay out of the Content Editor.

The Experience Editor doesn't have item bucket search/filter functionality; like filter by template, author, etc.
[image]

Question:  Does anyone have experience/recommendations for making item bucket content search/filterable within the Experience Editor?

7/9:  Adding clarification - Within the Experience Editor we're limited to the 'browse to' functionality in the navigation bar...
[image]
I'm curious about any options to use the search/filter functionality from within the search tab of the Content Editor, but from within the Experience Editor.  The ultimate goal is to keep the author out of the Content Editor.

Comment: I think I'm a little clear of your intended use case to bring buckets into the experience editor? Is it a specific field that uses the query builder?

Comment: in general doesn't work but if you give us type of the field you need to use maybe we find a solution

Comment: Hey Dylan - We're bucketing articles that are based on an article data template.  That template has a lot of taxonomy that authors would want to use to filter on (category, tag, author, etc.).   I don't think what I'm asking about exists in the Experience Editor, but wanted to ask.

Comment: @JamesWilliamson It sounds like to me that you are looking to search articles, which wouldn't necessarily happen on your current front end website, but more as a tool inside Sitecore for the purpose of finding articles, does that sound about right?  I'm not sure there is a way to do that currently.  You probably would have to build a custom speak application which you could trigger from a command in the dialog.  However if you have the ability to filter for everyone (content editor + visitor) you could use the Content Search API and build a rendering that can search for all of those criteria.